# MPAndroidChart is not showing bar chart values

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

In my application i am displaying feedback graph using MPAndroidChart library. Below are the issues i am facing.

1. Rating Values are not showing for graphs always, in few cases it is showing values, but in other cases it is not showing[image: rating values not showing]
2. If chart values are showing, those are not yet center of bar, it shows above each bar value, **It is really confusing the user which value is for which rating**[image]

I have read some related posts and tried to set min value as 0, but it does not fix value.

```
barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0f);
```

**Can someone suggest on how can make the graphs to always show values and values must be center?**